# gobject/gnome/glib bindings for D using GIR?

Tags: binding, d, gnome, glib, gobject

Does anyone know if there are bindings for the gobject family of librares (glib, Gnome, clutter, etc) available for the D language that use the GIR introspection mechanism?

I would like to write an app targeting GTK 3 and Clutter. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find them. Given that GIR should allow bindings to be generated automatically for all libraries that have introspection information available, this surprises me. Does such a thing actually exist? (One big drawback of D is that it's practically impossible to search for on Google...)

(Incidentally, I do know about [gtkD](http://www.dsource.org/projects/gtkd), but that only targets GTK 2 and doesn't do Clutter.)

Comment: Gnome 3 is a rather new release. D is a rather small community. So no, bindings do not exist at this time.

Comment: I have actually had a look at doing it myself --- using XSLT to transform the .gir files into source code doesn't look hard. Unfortunately it would seem that the D compiler that's in Debian is only D 1.0, so it's not really worth doing... If you rephrase your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Ta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it would appear that there aren't any.